# TopMost Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Possuo duas telas em Windows Forms que estão habilitadas com topmost, porém quando a segunda janela abre, a primeira(que também está com top most) fica por baixo, porém necessito que ambas as janelas fiquem por cima do windows, porém a janela1 deve ficar sempre em cima da janela2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se as duas estão definidas como `TopMost`, sempre ficará por cima a última que estava com foco ou a última que foi aberta. Mas se você quer que ao abrir a janela2, a janela1 apareça por cima, você pode chamar o método `.BringToFront();` da janela1.

Exemplo:

```
 Form2 janela1;
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        janela1 = new Form2();
        janela1.Text = "1";
        janela1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        janela1.TopMost = true;
        janela1.Show();

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 janela2 = new Form2();
        janela2.Text = "2";
        janela2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        janela2.TopMost = true;
        janela2.Show();
        if (janela1 != null && !janela1.IsDisposed)
            janela1.BringToFront();
    }
```